# Work done from force-extension graph

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

[image]

The answer is C, but I got B...

F at 3cm = 10, F at 6cm = 20

$W=F\cdot s$

$(20-10)\times 3=30$

I must have made a mistake or stupid assumption then, how am I meant to get 45 N cm?

Comment: work done is equal to energy transferred to the system. In this case, just calculate the EPE at 6cm and at 3cm- the difference in energy must have been provided by an external agent.

Comment: Because you ignored "from 3.0 cm to 6.0 cm"...

Answer (score 1):

You find the work done in the graph as the area underneath the line. Calculate this area between the required extensions